# How to create array of classes in android

Tags: android, arrays

I have a list of classes that i would like to store in an Array or  any data structure that would suite my problem. The array should be available across all the package and each element of the classes should be accessible from within the array. Its an Android app.

Comment: Please post the code you wrote in an attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterWard = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,AbiaStateRepository.wards[LG_pointer],android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapterWard.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_text_color);
        spinnerWard.setAdapter(adapterWard);
        spinnerWard.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

Comment: @user2341215 what exactly you want to do?

Comment: @user2341215 edit post and explain more!
with the source code

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin:

```
val class1 = Class1()
val class2 = Class2()

val list = ArrayList<Any>()

list.add(class1)
list.add(class2)
```

`Any` means you can store any type of object in it. Kotlin `SmartCast` allows you to check from `ArrayList` as well

In Java:

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1()
Class2 class2 = new Class2()

ArrayList list = new ArrayList<Object>()

list.add(class1)
list.add(class2)
```

You can store `ArrayList` in `SharedPreferences` and can use it in the whole `application`.

Here is sample code (You can optimize it)

```
public void saveArrayList(ArrayList<Object> list, String key){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    editor.putString(key, json);
    editor.apply();     // This line is IMPORTANT !!!
}

public ArrayList<Object> getArrayList(String key){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString(key, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Object>>() {}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Here you fetch the `object` from `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList list = getArrayList("some key");
  for (int counter = 0; counter < list.size(); counter++) {               
          if(list[counter] instance of class1) {
    // you have class1 object
           }    
          if(list[counter] instance of class2){
          // you have class2 object
           }

      }
```

Comment: in your "In java" solution how to you call the object reference from the array? this is because i get the name of the class plus some alphanumeric strings attached... This is what i get when i use getInt(), "com.example.dafibos.AbiaStateRepository@8451ba". i dont want the @8451ba attached

Answer (score -1):

if you don't need to persist the list, i think it will be better to use a **singelton** that contains a class list